# create series of value labels in r

Tags: r, label

My data looks like this:

```
               outc_n state region
largezip1_outc     96    FL      1
largezip2_outc     74    FL      2
largezip3_outc    251    FL      3
largezip4_outc    176    FL      4
largezip5_outc    161    FL      5
largezip6_outc     95    FL      6
```

How can I automatically create labels for region so that it looks like this?

```
               outc_n state   region
largezip1_outc     96    FL   FL-L-1
largezip2_outc     74    FL   FL-L-2
largezip3_outc    251    FL   FL-L-3
largezip4_outc    176    FL   FL-L-4
largezip5_outc    161    FL   FL-L-5
largezip6_outc     95    FL   FL-L-6
```

thanks!

Comment: What does `L` mean in your desired output?

Comment: short for large

Comment: so are they all L or are they only L because the first column says "largezip..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- 
read.table(text = "               outc_n state region
largezip1_outc     96    FL      1
largezip2_outc     74    FL      2
largezip3_outc    251    FL      3
largezip4_outc    176    FL      4
largezip5_outc    161    FL      5
largezip6_outc     95    FL      6")

dat %>%
  mutate(region = paste(state, "L", region, sep = "-"))
```

You could change what goes in place of the `L` in the `paste()` statement programatically with some minor edits.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to add `L` because the first letter of the row names are `L`, we can use `paste` to concatenate different strings.

```
dat$region <- with(dat, paste(state,
                              toupper(substring(rownames(dat), 1, 1)),
                              region,
                              sep = "-"))
dat
#                outc_n state region
# largezip1_outc     96    FL FL-L-1
# largezip2_outc     74    FL FL-L-2
# largezip3_outc    251    FL FL-L-3
# largezip4_outc    176    FL FL-L-4
# largezip5_outc    161    FL FL-L-5
# largezip6_outc     95    FL FL-L-6
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "               outc_n state region
largezip1_outc     96    FL      1
                  largezip2_outc     74    FL      2
                  largezip3_outc    251    FL      3
                  largezip4_outc    176    FL      4
                  largezip5_outc    161    FL      5
                  largezip6_outc     95    FL      6",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
 df <- read.table(header=T, text="large outc_n state region
                       largezip1_outc     96    FL      1
                       largezip2_outc     74    FL      2
                       largezip3_outc    251    FL      3
                       largezip4_outc    176    FL      4
                       largezip5_outc    161    FL      5
                       largezip6_outc     95    FL      6")

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
## using paste0 to paste different values of columns desired and getting 
## first letter of first column and converting it to upper case as desired
df[, region := paste0(state, "-", toupper(substr(large, 1, 1)), "-", region)]


           large   outc_n state region
1: largezip1_outc     96    FL FL-L-1
2: largezip2_outc     74    FL FL-L-2
3: largezip3_outc    251    FL FL-L-3
4: largezip4_outc    176    FL FL-L-4
5: largezip5_outc    161    FL FL-L-5
6: largezip6_outc     95    FL FL-L-6
```